# Summing up fields with an exception

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports, ireport

Currently I have a report that has a setup like this:

[image]

What I want to do is make those variables (sumaccts_1 & sumbalance_1) add up the fields (numaccts & sumbalance) with an exception to whether $F{attribution} is 'n' instead of 'y'

Here is what it looks like currently when I generate it:

[image]

So as you can see at the moment those summed up amounts are including the row with the 'n' and I would like it to only sum up the amounts with 'y'.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For total accounts, create a variable of type Integer, calculation Sum, reset type Report, and variable expression:

```
 $F{attribution} == "y" ? $F{numaccts} : 0
```

For total amount, you should use a variable type of your choice that is more appropriate for a decimal value.